# Add Blank Space in Access 2010 Listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010, multi-select

I have a multi select listbox in Access 2010 that is basically formatted to look and act like a combo box. Ie. The field is only tall enough to show one option, and the size changes with the getfocus and lostfocus events. The field is unbound and the row source is a lookup table.

What I want to do is to make it so that either there's a blank space before the first option, or something to that effect. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Can't you add an empty string e.g. ""?

Comment: I could try, but I'm not entirely sure where. Access isn't really my forte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this in the Listbox's RowSource

```
SELECT "" AS TestValue FROM ATestTable
UNION
SELECT TestValue
FROM ATestTable
```

To do this, you will have probably have to edit the Listbox's RowSource in SQL View to add the first two lines.  An important thing to note when using a Union is the columns all need to have the same name.